# \0 character in istream::getline()

Tags: c++, getline, istream, null-terminated

What happens if a file contains a `\0` character when using `istream::getline()`? Will be it be omitted or still assigned into a field in the string buffer?

Comment: There's no method `readline()` . And what is `\0` is a file btw ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant istream::getline() I don't see why a null char would ignored. Reading the description on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline I see nothing that treats \0 in any special way unless you use it as the delimiter.

Short story: it get placed in the extracted string.

Answer (score 0):

From [std::istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)

> A null character ('\0') is automatically appended to the written
>   sequence if n is greater than zero, even if an empty string is
>   extracted.